# how to store modelform data to database

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

> I have searched 20-30 posts and I did not find anything useful. I am to store data to database by selecting values from HTML file or form in view. Please tell me how I can achieve this. what code I am missing. Thanks in advance for Help.
>
> view.py

```
   def blog_list(request):
form = AttendanceForm()
if request.method == "POST":
    form1 = AttendanceForm(request.POST)
    if form1.is_valid:
        form1.save()
        return render(request, 'blog/blog_list.html',{
        'form1':form1,
        })

return render(request, 'blog/blog_list.html',{
    'form':form,
    })
```

> my forms.py

```
class AttendanceForm(forms.ModelForm):
        action = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Action.objects.all(), empty_label="-----------", required=True)
        employee = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Employee.objects.all(), empty_label="-----------", required=True)
        class Meta:
            model = Action
            fields = ['employee','action']
```

> my model.py

```
    class Action(models.Model): 
    action_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.action_name

class Employee(models.Model):
    employee_id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    employee_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.employee_name

class Attendance(models.Model):
    u = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    action = models.ForeignKey(Action)
    action_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working fine after these changes in Model:

```
class Action(models.Model): 
    action_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.action_name

class Employee(models.Model):
    employee_id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    employee_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.employee_name

class Attendance(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    action = models.ForeignKey(Action)
    action_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python you need to call methods by using parentheses.

```
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
```

Comment: getting error  :  IntegrityError at /
null value in column "u_id" violates not-null constraint